# How to simulate an uncompleted Netty ChannelFuture

Tags: udp, netty

I'm using Netty to write a client application that sends UDP messages to a server. In short I'm using this piece of code to write the stream to the channel:

```
ChannelFuture future = channel.write(request, remoteInetSocketAddress);
future.awaitUninterruptibly(timeout);
if(!future.isDone()){
   //abort logic
}
```

Everything works fine, but one thing: I'm unable to test the abort logic as I cannot make the write to fail - i.e. even if the server is down the future would be completed successfully. The write operation usually takes about 1 ms so setting very little timeout doesn't help too much.

I know the preffered way would be to use an asynch model instead of await() call, however for my scenario I need it to be synchronous and I need to be sure it get finnished at some point.

Does anyone know how could I simulate an uncompleted future?

Many thanks in advance!
MM

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your code is written you could use a mock framework such as mockito. If that is not possible, you can also use a "connected" UDP socket, i.e. a datagram socket that is bound to a local address. If you send to a bogus server you should get PortunreachableException or something similar.

Comment: Yes, the mocking may be a solution, but I would like to see a real reason for the future not being completed. Sending packets to a bogus server doesn't work - the future is actually completed sucessfully.

Comment: Looking at your example again, I see that the answer above doesn't really match the question. Are you sure you want too look at isDone()? If false, it simply means that the write operation is not completed and may still come out successfully or unsuccessfully. I blindly assumed you meant isSuccess(). In that case, sending to "0.0.0.0" port 1 causes a failure.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I'm sure I want to look at isDone(). Actually I have a production issue and I observed isDone() returns false in my case. The problem is I cannot reproduce the issue in test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Netty has a class FailedFuture that can be used for the purpose of this,

You can for example mock your class with tests that simulate the following:

```java
ChannelFuture future;
if(ALWAYS_FAIL) {
    future = channel.newFailedFuture(new Exception("I failed"));
else
    future = channel.write(request, remoteInetSocketAddress);
```